# Eclipse shows error decorator

Tags: eclipse

I have created a Maven project with JPA and JFS Facets in eclipse. In the project explorer the folder "Java resources" is decorated with white cross on a red background, which means that there are errors at least in one file contained in the folder. But this is not the case! Is this an eclipse bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Open the 'Problems' view and see if that lists any errors.

Comment: Thank you, indeed there are some errors listed.